# does it make sense to pass the android R to another class?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I'm making this activity that accepts data for a form from an xml and renders the form on the screen. Now the code to do the actual rendering is in a separate java file (there are basically 3 types of questions, each with their own method to render the data extracted from xml)Its basically like this.

```
public void newQuestion(String question, LinearLayout l, Context c){
        TextView tv = new TextView(c);
        tv.setText(question);
        EditText et = new EditText(c);
        l.addView(tv);
        l.addView(et);

    }
```

So this is my problem - To have this Java file add widgets to the form I need to pass the Context of the activity. Also, I'll need to be able to access the layout ( simple linear layout) to add to. Can you just pass the R or import it (android.R) in the other java file ? Coz then I can get the context and layout and all requisite ids from R.

---

I did try importing it. My java classes are in project A and my android activity is a separate project B. So I wrote

```
import B.src.com.android.*;
```

and it says " the import B couldnt be resolved"  [I tried B.com.android too . Same error]

Comment: Of course you can import it, why not? Have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In sense of pass R file ,You don't need to pass  it.
```

You can access R file from any class of project.**and you have to import it.**

```
import com.company.product.R;
```